# Remove spaces between rows

Tags: css, ionic-framework, col

Im facing a little issue with rows and the space between of them. On the other hand, im try too setup the images to filled (in the same size) the initial home page (with navbar and tabspage).

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nO4s.jpg)

and my code for now:
page.html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col no-padding (click)="openPage1()">
      <p class="image-title">1</p>
      <img  src="assets/imgs/2560x1440.png" />
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col no-padding (click)="openPage2()">
      <p class="image-title">2</p>
      <img  src="assets/imgs/2560x1440.png" />
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col no-padding (click)="openPage3()">
      <p class="image-title">3</p>
      <img  src="assets/imgs/2560x1440.png" />
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

page.scss:

```
page-tests1 {
}
  ion-row {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .image-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    font-size: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
  }
```

Comment: Please create a code snippet and upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you haven't use reset css. Please add this css for image because this space from img default style.

Or i will suggest to use global [reset](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_reboot.scss)

or you can use eric meyer [reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

```
img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks @Kumar